# Is it a good idea to create a githook, which makes git squash the latest (not pushed) commits?

Tags: git, githooks

In my opinion, in small and dynamic projects, creating many commits during a working day is very common. I started wondering if it is a good idea, to create a githook, which will help squash commits before the final push and merge.

I am wondering if anyone works already with this kind of workflow?

Comment: That depends. Do you want your commits to be squashed, or not?

Answer (score 1):

Subsuming several commits into one commit is possible. But you will contradict most of gits features.

I'd like to refer to a [Blog-Post](http://blog.crealytics.com/2010/07/09/5-reasons-keeping-git-commits-small-admin/) of Matthias Lüdtke, which suggests you to **keep the commits as small as possible** for the following reasons:

- It makes your commit-messages more accurate (the short commit messages probably more precise if they must not describe a lot of work)
- It makes continuous integration easier (if a build fails based on a small commit the bug will be found faster)
- It makes [`git revert`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-revert.html) more useful (it enables you to revert precise changes)
- It makes [`git bisect`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Debugging-with-Git#Binary-Search) more useful (it enables you to conquer and divide in which commit a bug was introduced)
- It allows a more accurate cherry-pick (you are enabled to cherry-pick small changes)
- It documents better what happened (since a document may have changed twice a day for different reasons)

After all, if you feel you'd like to squash up your changes, [you may do so](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/10/squashing-commits-with-rebase.html) - but i wouldn't recommend.

Answer (score 0):

I'm usually committing, changing and `git add/rm` files again and then use:

```
git commit --amend
```

during work period. It leads to the same result as if you would commit again and then squash the 2 most recent commits.

Comment: But what if, at the end of the day, you have made 15 commits and decide you want to remove commit #6 before you squash them all?

Comment: What you say here is true to some extent but it implies that `git commit --amend` is a command that squashes the 2 last commits, which it does not

Comment: Isn't it the same as if I would commitA, commitB and then squash them afterwards?

Comment: No, `git commit --amend` modifies the previous commit with your newly added/removed changes. Also gives you the option to edit the commit message

Comment: ... and changes the commit hash. So what is the difference?

Comment: *It is the same as if you would squash the 2 most recent commits.* thi s is only so if the new changes were already added and committed. If you amend you modify the last commit with the new changes that are **not** committed

Comment: I implied that `git add/rm` happens before amending (because only this makes sense here). I've added this information to the answer.

Comment: The essential difference is the extra commit that you would need for a squash to lead to the same result as an amend would give *without* that extra commit

Comment: Please read my answer again, I've reworded it and wrote "it leads to the same result". This is definitely true and much easier to achieve than an explicit squash. That's why I gave the answer. OP seems unsure and asks for alternatives.

Comment: *It leads to the same result as **if you would commit again and then squash** the 2 most recent commits* that's exactly what I meant, thanks for editing it I'll remove the downvote

Comment: Ok. Seems that we both meant the same. I'm glad that the rewording could solve the issue